# How to track ruby-on-rails validation failures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, sentry, issue-tracking

My colleagues from support often tell me that customers are not able to fill in this form because of a bug.

The form is very large, sometimes, it is a legitimate bug, sometimes it is just a validation issue of the form (not technically a bug but let's say a usability bug). 
Sometimes the validation itself is just a bug (like the format of a field has changed and the form will never be valid).

I use sentry.io to track errors, but is there a way to track form validation failures ?

I suppose I could use another tool that sentry but I am also interested to know I could make a special callback on all form validations to either send an issue to sentry, email, etc

thx

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is rescue from `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` error and do whatever you want to do with validation failures

```
begin
  complex_form.save!
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
  ErrorMailer.delay.send(invalid.record.errors)
end
```

Comment: thanks, I will try to implement your suggestion and get back